# javascript two trigger function on input button

Tags: javascript

Hi i would like few textboxes disabled when a textbox contains a specific text and i click a button.

Here is what I have:
button:

```
<div id="itemRows1">
<label ></label><input type="hidden" name="add_name1" /><input onclick="addRow1(this.form); " type="button" id="dodaj1" value="Dodaj tip droge in količino" class="btn btn-primary"  />
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
var dis1 = document.getElementById("preiskavoopr1");
  dis1.onchange = function () {
     if (this.value == "SKP" ) {
      document.getElementById("dolgnaziv").disabled = true;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control1");
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                 x[i].disabled = true;
      }

   } else { 
            document.getElementById("dolgnaziv").disabled = false; 
     }
}
</script>
```

The button is adding more fields dinamicaly and is working as expected.
The text box with the id preiskavoopr1 is a drop down with 2 values and is OK.

When i select a value SKP in the dropdown the text boxes with ClassName("form-control1"); has to become disabled and that is working. But when i click on the button 2 more text boxes with the ClassName("form-control1"); appears not disabled but they should be.

Hope i explained well enough.

Comment: `frm.add_name.value = '';` You have multiple elements with the name "add_name" so not sure what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: @epascarello i would like the button with in the div id"itemRows1" to do the same thing of the last script at the bottom (load on click that script again)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to add onclick methods to `<input>` elements which disguised into a button because you added `class="btn btn-primary"` to it.

Change your button to
`<button onclick="addRow()" class="btn btn-primary">Button Text</button>`

Comment: @matejtu you can do it by adding event listener to the element. Try giving your `<input>` tag an ID and adding this to your script `document.getElementById("yourButtonId").addEventListener("click", yourButtonFunction);`

Comment: @matejtu add this line after your button function `dis1.addEventListener("cl‌​ick", dis1.onchange);`